# After changing android toolbar to transparent color the overflow button has gone missing

Tags: android, android-toolbar

After adding the toolbar, following android developer API i decided to change the color of the background to transparent as I have a spinner i want to place in the top corner. As soon as i did that the overflow button (three dots) goes missing

Here is the code to set up the toolbar:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("");

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Instruments, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

the XML layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to place my toolbar xml inside a relative layout xml. The overflowicon was off the phone screen. This fixed the issue.